# find a matrix that satisfies $A^6= I$...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

How to solve this type of questions .....please explain....

I'm not getting how to start?

Comment: is this a home-work question?

Comment: The naive way is to just calculate $A^6$ by hand and hope that you obtain $A$. A better way is to think about what these $A$'s are doing geometrically. Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions

Comment: So then it's $2$?

Comment: its very time-taking to find $A^6$ for all the four options in exam....is there any shortcut way to find the solution?

Comment: @  Jorge Fernández...please explain...

Comment: @Prasanta: Have you thought about what I wrote? Or have you at least read the link I posted?

Comment: @  sranthrop...I'm reading the link you have posted...can you provide more hint how it is 2....

Comment: I'll explain it on (1). My link would have let you know that $A$ is a rotation matrix which rotates points around the $z$-axes by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Then $A^2=A\cdot A$ rotates by $2\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}$, and $A^3$ rotates by $3\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}$. So $A^6$ rotates by? Can this be the identity mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)&0\\-\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
represents a rotation on the $z-$axis (in the 3D space) of an angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Therefore your first matrix represents a rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ on the $z-$axis, and applying $6$ times such a rotation you are actually applying a rotation of $6\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, which is not the identity, because you are missing a quarter of a rotation to get a full one.

Similarly the second matrix represents a rotation on the $x-$axis of an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Applying $6$ times such a rotation you have a rotation of $6\cdot \frac{\pi}{3}=2\pi$, i.e: you are applying an entire rotation of $2\pi$ and therefore you will get the identity.

For the third one, the rotation is on the $y-$axis, and is of an angle of $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Applying it $6$ times leads to a rotation of $\pi$, which is not the identity.

Are you able to do the last case? The final answer is that only the second matrix satisfies $A^6=I$.